# set value using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm tring to make this work

```
Type ReflectionObject = r.GetType();
var field = ReflectionObject.GetField("Frame");
field.SetValue(r, 2);
```

But it doesn not work. I've set a breakpoint and I see that I get no fields. So for tests I've created Model with one field "test"

```
namespace Recorder.Models
{
class Recording : Recorder.Recording
{
    int test { get; set; }
}
}
```

and made my code even simpler

```
Recorder.Models.Recording r = new Recorder.Models.Recording();
var fields = r.GetType().GetFields();
```

still "fields" is empty. What is wrong with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's a Property, not a field. Try this:

```
var prop = ReflectionObject.GetProperty("Frame");
prop.SetValue(r, 2);
```

Comment: I've just noticed that :) thanks from confirming it. Now I need to save it in database